# Extend all prototypes

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have a few jQuery prototype methods:

```
$.fn.one
$.fn.two
$.fn.three
```

Each has their own code and I want to add something to the end of all three.  Lets say console.log('done').  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rebind the names to new functions that call their previous incarnations, then invoke `console.log()`.

Something like:

```
$.each(["one", "two", "three"], function(index, name) {
    var originalMethod = $.fn[name];
    $.fn[name] = function() {
        var result = originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log(name + "() done.");
        return result;
    };
});
```

If you want to apply this behavior to all the methods in jQuery's prototype, you can iterate over `$.fn` itself and only process functions:

```
for (var name in $.fn) {
    // Create a new scope so 'originalMethod' is still bound to the
    // right method by the time our new '$.fn[name]()' is invoked.
    (function(originalMethod) {
        if ($.isFunction(originalMethod)) {
            $.fn[name] = function() {
                var result = originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
                console.log(name + "() done.");
                return result;
            };
        }
    })($.fn[name]);
}
```

Comment: Nice, how about a way to access all declared methods instead of listing them in an array?

Comment: *All* the methods in jQuery's prototype? Are you sure?

Comment: No just methods I have declared not the built in ones.

Comment: That's why I used an array of names. How would you make a difference between "built-in" (actually "not your") methods, and "yours"?

Comment: Wasn't sure if jQuery stored them differently.  I guess back the first question then.  Any way to get all methods including built in ones and mine?

Comment: Yup, iterating directly over `$.fn` and filtering through `$.isFunction()` should work I believe. I'll update my answer.

Comment: First one works fine, however $.fn does not return a list of methods.

Comment: @Residual, fixed that by iterating by hand. I have to say I'm not very comfortable with hooking the whole prototype like that, use this code at your own risk :)